# Filtering a list of tuples filled with None in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, filter

Let's say I have a list of tuples like the following:

```
my_list = [(2, 3), (3, None), (None, None), (3, 4), (None, 2)]
```

How can I filter this list in order to:

1. Remove all tuples containing **at least one** `None`
2. Remove **only** the tuples that **both values** are `None`

So the outcome in each case should be:

1. `[(2, 3), (3, 4)]`
2. `[(2, 3), (3, None), (3, 4), (None, 2)]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter on your specific conditions:

```
no_none = [t for t in my_list if None not in t]
some_none = [t for t in my_list if t != (None, None)]
```

Note that filtering selects elements that *don't* match your criteria, so the first picks all tuples that don't contain `None`, the second picks all tuples that are not equal to the `(None, None)` tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = [(2, 3), (3, None), (None, None), (3, 4), (None, 2)]
>>> [t for t in my_list if None not in t]
[(2, 3), (3, 4)]
>>> [t for t in my_list if t != (None, None)]
[(2, 3), (3, None), (3, 4), (None, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all` to ensure all are not `None`, and you can use `any` for the expression: any value is not `None`.

```
>>> my_list = [(2,3), (3,None), (None,None), (3,4), (None,2)]
>>> filter(lambda x:all(i is not None for i in x), my_list)
[(2, 3), (3, 4)]
>>> filter(lambda x:any(i is not None for i in x), my_list)
[(2, 3), (3, None), (3, 4), (None, 2)]
```

Comment: `all()` is not necessary even in the arbitrary-length case; `None not in x` doesn't care how many elements are in `x`. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters any might be necessary when we have more than 2 elements and we cant write (None, None) for the 2nd case